# Bridge Movie Night

Tags: discussion, community-event

A few people had the idea to do a Bridge-wide movie night, so let's coordinate one!

- **Movie**: Wreck It Ralph (+Paperman)
- **When**: *Two Showings*

  - 2:00 PM Saturday Jan 3rd, 2015 PST
  - 5:00 PM Saturday Jan 3rd, 2015 PST
- **Where**: [Online Here](https://rabb.it/ktash)
- **Who**: Anyone who would like to join

We'll make sure to post about it and make noise in chat so that everyone remembers. And, of course, you can pop in and out as you like :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas for logistics? I'm not even really sure I understand what you're proposing.

Comment: @StrixVaria We all watch a movie together. There is a chat room, and it will play the movie in a shared video space. Rabbit is a shared video watching service that allows us to all watch together

Comment: @yuuki I can't speak for anyone else who attended, but this was really fun. Thanks for taking the time and effort to set this up and host!

Comment: @GodEmperorDune Greater credit should go to Ktash. He helped find the web service we used for movie night and came up with a schedule. Not to mention he put up this meta post.

Comment: @Yuuki sorry for being unclear, I was trying to thank both of you but SE would only let me link one name and ktash was already copied as the question owner.

Answer (score 9):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Wreck It Ralph Movie Poster by Disney]

*Wreck It Ralph* is a recent Disney movie about a video game villain seeking acceptance. In the movie are a lot of references to video games, gaming, and pop culture, and it is all wrapped up in a nice story with lovable characters. The film is rated PG for some rude humor and mild action/violence.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87E6N7ToCxs) | [Official Site](http://movies.disney.com/wreck-it-ralph) | [Buy on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A7OIXW6) | [Rotten Tomatoes (86%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/wreck_it_ralph)

Answer (score 5):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Scott Pilgrim vs. the World Movie Poster by Universal Pictures]

*Scott Pilgrim VS. the World* is based on a set of comic books and follows the adventures of Scott Pilgrim as he tries to win the heart of a girl he likes by battling her evil ex-es... **TO THE DEATH**. While not directly gaming related, the movie is heavily gaming influenced and features a lot of shout-outs to gaming and gaming culture throughout. The film is rated PG-13 for stylized violence, sexual content, language and drug references. IMDB has a [parental guide to the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0446029/parentalguide) which lists some of the content of the movie which some may find objectionable.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NUBVcit5VM) | [Official Site](http://www.scottpilgrimthemovie.com/) | [Buy on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041T52S6) | [Rotten Tomatoes (82%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/scott_pilgrims_vs_the_world/)

Answer (score 5):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: MOON]

Astronaut Sam Bell has a quintessentially personal encounter toward the end of his three-year stint on the Moon, where he, working alongside his computer, GERTY, sends back to Earth parcels of a resource that has helped diminish our planet's power problems.

## If you have not seen it, do not read about it beforehand.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twuScTcDP_Q) | [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030B621W) | [Rotten Tomatoes (89%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/10009075-moon/)

---

Moon is [Rated R](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/parentalguide) for language and some mildly disturbing scenes, but on the whole it's actually pretty tame.  And one of my favourite films ever.

Answer (score 2):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Looper]

In 2074, when the mob wants to get rid of someone, the target is sent into the past, where a hired gun awaits - someone like Joe - who one day learns the mob wants to 'close the loop' by sending back Joe's future self for assassination.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iQuhsmtfHw) | [Official Site](http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/looper/) | [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A9X9TIW) | [Rotten Tomatoes (93%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/looper/)

---

This movie is rated R for a bunch of stuff like violence and cursing,and has brief boobies.