# Bridge Movie Night 2: Bridge Movie Nighter

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

After [the rousing success of our first Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/bridge-movie-night), it's been decided that a second Bridge Movie Night is in order. The format will be roughly the same, we'll use [Rabbit](https://rabb.it/ktash) so that everyone can stream the same movie and there'll be a text chat on the side if you want to talk. As with the previous Movie Night, we'll try our best to have multiple showings throughout the day so people in as many time zones can participate.

I have a few movies in mind, please vote for whichever one you want to watch. If a movie you want to watch isn't listed, go ahead and suggest it. Please be aware that we reserve the right to disqualify any movies that we are unable to obtain. We will, however, try our best to get our hands on whatever is the top-voted suggestion.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to tally up the votes at the end of the weekend. Since *Big Hero 6* is currently the frontrunner, if second place is close enough in the vote tally, we'll either have two movie nights this month or move *Big Hero 6* to March, given that it doesn't release until the tail end of February.

Comment: I don't presume this legal, is it?

Comment: @RavenM This is no different than you inviting your friends over for a Netflix movie night. We have a number of people (myself included) who have access either through Netflix or purchasing on Google Play or Amazon or a host of other legal streaming websites. Those people will log in to the Rabbit sharing service and everyone watches their stream.

Comment: @Yuuki Just wanted to say, it's great that you're doing this :)  Last year was very fun.

Comment: So, while watching the movie "Guardians of the Galaxy", some people were thinking about how this should be a monthly club.  We soon realised that this would be a problem, since the films would degrade in quality quickly.  Would having one of these happening every time a good film comes out be better?  It takes only a few minutes to setup, and all that needs to happen is that the person owns the film.  Rabb.it appears to be free for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Movie Decision

All right, folks, given the close run between *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Big Hero 6* along with the fact that *Big Hero 6* won't be released until the end of the month, here's what we're going to do.

Sometime starting next week, we'll decide on a weekend to do a showing of *Guardians of the Galaxy*. I've decided against doing the showing this weekend on account of the New Nintendo 3DS release and how many people will most likely be busy with either *Majora's Mask 3D* or *Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate*.

Then, sometime in March after *Big Hero 6* has been released, we'll schedule a showing for *Big Hero 6*.  Keep a watch on this post, I'll try to keep it updated for when we decide on a date.

- <strike>*Guardians of the Galaxy* showtimes: February 21/22 (Saturday and Sunday). Showings will begin at 10:00PM UTC-0</strike> *Showing past*
- *Big Hero 6* showtimes: **March 14/15** (Saturday and Sunday). Showings will begin at **10:00PM UTC-0**

We typically take about 10-15 minutes between each showing and we'll announce in chat roughly 5-10 minutes before each showing begins. Rabbit has its own chat feature and everyone's encouraged to talk about the movie while watching, although we discourage spoilers as some people may be watching for the first time.

Answer (score 20):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Guardians of the Galaxy Movie Poster]

*Guardians of the Galaxy* is another rousing entry in Marvel's monumental Cinematic Universe. Unlike the others however, *Guardians of the Galaxy* takes place almost entirely far away from Earth. The eponymous Guardians are: Peter Quill, a thief and miscreant who calls himself [Star Lord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiFWR.gif); Gamora, a shadowy assassin; Drax the Destroyer, an alien warrior seeking revenge for the death of his family; Rocket, a bounty hunter who's just looking to make some money; and Groot, Rocket's partner-in-crime who also happens to be a giant tree. Safe to say, they're not your average superhero team. Ride along as the Guardians travel the galaxy doing their best (not really) to save the galaxy (really more a single planet) from Ronan, a genocidal villain, out of the goodness of their hearts. Yeah, let's go with that. This film is rated PG-13 for intense sequences of sci-fi violence and action, and for some language.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d96cjJhvlMA) | [Official Site](http://marvel.com/guardians) | [Rotten Tomatoes (91%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/guardians_of_the_galaxy) | [Parental Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/parentalguide)

Answer (score 17):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Big Hero 6 Movie Poster]

Fresh off the success of their animated films with *Frozen* and their live-action Marvel Cinematic Universe, Disney has decided to combine the two in *Big Hero 6*. Hiro Hamada is a teenager growing in the city of San Fransokyo. When a mysterious villain terrorizes his city, he and his group of friends suit up to defend their home and find out the bad guy's identity. This film is rated PG for action and peril, some rude humor, and thematic elements. [The IMDB parental guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg) provides some further information on possibly objectionable content.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khtFNzVPIh8) | [Official Site](http://movies.disney.com/big-hero-6/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (90%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/big_hero_6)

Comment: A note for those voting: This movie won't come out until later this month, so if this is chosen, it will likely push out the date we do the movie a bit.

Answer (score 6):

### Movie Suggestion: *The Tale of Princess Kaguya*

[image: Not a Miyazaki film]]

*The Tale of The Princess Kaguya* is adapted from the 10th century Japanese folktale "[The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter)," by Studio Ghibli co-founder [Isao Takahata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isao_Takahata) (you may know him from *[Grave of the Fireflies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vPeTSRd580)*, *[Pom Poko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7cowIHjCD4)*). It is the oldest Japanese narrative in existence and an early example of proto-science fiction. The story details the life of a mysterious girl called "Kaguya-hime," who was discovered as a baby inside the stalk of a glowing bamboo plant and is raised by a poor bamboo cutter and his wife.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM6hcHp0_kU) | [Site](http://www.gkidsfilms.com/kaguya/) | [Fresh! (100%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_tale_of_the_princess_kaguya/) | [Content Advisory Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2576852/parentalguide)

*Remarks:* While a Ghibli film, this is *not* a Hayao Miyazaki film. Production of this was done in parallel to *The Wind Rises.* Home release is scheduled for Feb. 17, 2015.

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: John Wick Poster]

*John Wick* is the story of a retired professional killer coming out of retirement, but not for one final job. After a mob boss's son steals his car and kills his dog, Wick is coming for vengeance. A cheesy storyline sure, but *John Wick* has clean-cut and crisp action setpieces. With beautiful fight choreography, *John Wick* more than makes up for its barebones storytelling. While not gaming-related, John Wick does have a video game tie-in as a character in *Payday 2*. This film is rated R for strong and bloody violence throughout, language and brief drug use. The [IMDB parental guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/parentalguide) lists some content which may be considered objectionable.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvaftiAu7mw) | [Official Site](http://www.johnwickthemovie.com) | [Rotten Tomatoes (83%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/john_wick)

Answer (score -2):

### Movie Suggestion: *Boyhood*

[image: 12 years a white kid]]

Filmed over 12 years with the same cast, the film tells a story of a divorced couple, Mason and Olivia, raising their young son, Mason Jr. The story follows the boy for twelve years, from first grade at age 6 through twelfth grade at age 18, and examines his relationship with his parents as he grows.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0oX0xiwOv8) | [Site](http://boyhoodmovie.tumblr.com/) | [Fresh! (98%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/boyhood/) | [Content Advisory Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1065073/parentalguide)

*Remarks:* I highly recommend this movie. It will hit *very* close to home for those born around '92 and '95. I don't mean to oversell, but it's very rare to find a film. The story and characters of Linklater's emotional powerhouse that will have you reflecting on the film in the hours to follow. But really, no matter who you are or where you come from (even you're *Stern-old*) -- this film will connect with you on some sort of level. It may not make you cry, but it should at least hit you in the feels one way or another.

*Who would like this movie?* The very reason many people would the movie before they even see it is because the think it's "too simple," with no great new plot. At the same reason a lot of others would like it for this exact reason. The movie is not an escape from reality, it is a mirror reflection of it. Obviously all the fantasy and action fans out there, will be in for major disappointment, but for the rest of us, it's a trip down memory lane. It's about the highs and lows of life, of failed relationships, of mistakes, regret involved with growing up and moving on.

Comment: This movie is almost 3 hours long.