# Bridge Movie Night 3: The Search For Popcorn

Tags: discussion, community-event

Bridge Movie Night is just getting [bigger](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/bridge-movie-night?lq=1) and [bigger](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/bridge-movie-night-2-bridge-movie-nighter). As I haven't heard any complaints so far, I think we're going to stick with the same format. This meta will open for voting and discussion for about two weeks or so, then a decision will be made regarding which movie to show. Now I realize that two movies from the last Movie Night selection were chosen. However, this was due to extenuating circumstances from the initial first choice's release date. This time around, we'll be picking one movie and one movie only.

As always, feel free to post your suggestions for movies. Please consider that the movies you propose must be available on a streaming service, be it Netflix, Amazon, Google, etc. If you have any questions regarding how to attend Bridge Movie Night, please refer to past meta posts. If you don't find an answer there, feel free to comment below or ask around in the Bridge chat room.

Comment: Ummm excuse me, but I want to vote for The Revenge of the Spugsley and I'm not seeing it on the list...?

Comment: Any new on when this is happening?

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Showtimes will be announced by the end of the coming weekend.

Comment: @Yuuki Great to hear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Movie Decision

The votes are in and the decision has been made (though a bit later than I had announced). The movie we will be watching for Bridge Movie Night 3 is... *(drumroll)*

[image: empty space]

## Song of the Sea

[image: Song of the Sea]

Showtimes will begin on **April 17th (Friday) at 11:00PM UTC-0**. If you can't make Friday, don't worry, there will be additional showings if requested on Saturday and Sunday. An event will be posted up in the Bridge as a reminder and there will be chat announcements 5-10 minutes before each showing. After each showing, there will be a 10-15 minute intermission before the next showing.

As always, moviegoers are encouraged to use the Rabbit chat features to talk about the movie, though spoilers are strongly discouraged as there may be people watching for the first time.

NOTE: Due to extenuating circumstances, the initial showtime on Friday has been pushed back by one hour. Showtime is now **11:00 PM UTC-0**. Again, the new initial showtime is now **11:00 PM UTC-0**.

Comment: Will there be multiple showings on Friday? I'd have to join in on Saturday, though. Friday is my birthday and I'm told I have plans.

Comment: @Coronus Yes, we will be doing multiple showings on Friday, Saturday, and Sunday depending on attendance.

Answer (score 12):

### Movie Suggestion: The Lego Movie

[image: The Lego Movie Poster]

Emmet (Chris Pratt), an ordinary construction worker, thought to be a prophesied 'Special', joins a quest to stop President/Lord Business (Will Ferrell) from releasing the Kragle and freezing the entire universe.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ_JOBCLF-I) | [Official Site](http://www.thelegomovie.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (96%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_lego_movie) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

If you look at this and say "this is just going to be a Lego brand cash grab film, isn't it", I can assure you, you are beyond incorrect. It had every opportunity to be a terrible Lego cash grab, but it's so much deeper than that.

Comment: I literally don't know how you guys made these synopsises so long... and I also don't know how to spell that word >_>

Comment: if this doesn't win, you should totally resubmit for next month

Comment: This movie was not as light-hearted as I expected it to be.

Comment: @John it's a light hearted movie at first, but it's like a switch labeled "Feels" gets flipped and then the flood gates open.

Comment: Yeah, I really enjoyed the movie up to that point.  After it, not so much...

Answer (score 10):

## Movie Suggestion: Song of the Sea

[image]

Nominated for the Academy Award for Best Animated Feature, *Song of the Sea* is a traditionally animated film based on the ancient Celtic myth of the selkie. Ben and Saoirse live in a lighthouse by the sea. Ben tries his best to be a good older brother to Saoirse after the death of their mother, but it's a bit tough when she's more than a little abnormal: though she is six years old, she has not spoken a word since she was born.

After being sent to live with their grandmother in the city, their mother's mysterious past begins to surface. And it's up to Ben and Saoirse to find their way back home.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgbXWt8kM5Q) | [Official Site](http://www.gkidsfilms.com/song/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (98%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/song_of_the_sea_2014/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1865505/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: This looks really good.

Comment: This sounds like something I'd love. :D

Answer (score 7):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

*How To Train Your Dragon 2* is Dreamwork's sequel to their big hit *How to Train Your Dragon*. Loosely based on the children's book series of the same name, *How To Train Your Dragon 2* (from hereon to be abbreviated as *HTTYD2*) takes place five years after the events of the first film. Having brought peace between the dragons and Vikings, Hiccup now finds himself teetering on the edge between a teenager and an adult.

But Hiccup's adolescent issues aren't the only problem on the horizon. A bloodthirsty warlord is coming for the Vikings, bringing an army the likes of which have never been seen: a dragon army. After only so recently ended the long dragon-Viking war, can Hiccup end the bloodshed peacefully?

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9a4PvzlqoQ) | [Official Site](https://www.howtotrainyourdragon.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (92%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/how_to_train_your_dragon_2) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1646971/parentalguide)

Comment: This is  fantastic movie, but I ended up watching this last week on Netflix, haha, so I don't feel like watching it again so soon, hence my downvote.

Answer (score 6):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Looper]

In 2074, when the mob wants to get rid of someone, the target is sent into the past, where a hired gun awaits - someone like Joe - who one day learns the mob wants to 'close the loop' by sending back Joe's future self for assassination.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iQuhsmtfHw) | [Official Site](http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/looper/) | [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A9X9TIW) | [Rotten Tomatoes (93%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/looper/)

---

This movie is rated TV for titties and violence.  Plus a lot of cursing.

Comment: +1 for an animated poster, -1 for the movie being a disappointment

Comment: Huh, you didn't like it?  I thought it was excellent.  Not quite what I was expecting, but still really good.

Comment: Movies about time travel and their implications that adamantly refuse to discuss the time travel annoy me. Their take on how it worked didn't have any internal consistency. Plus, while the idea of "closing the loop" sounds interesting and is clearly the idea that drove them to make the whole movie in the first place, when you actually stop to think about it, it's a concept that really makes no logical sense for the either in principle or execution by the guy who is ordering it. Plus, there's a point where Willis is clearly outgunned, yet "wins" off-camera. The whole movie felt lazy to me.

Comment: Looper got a lot more interesting about halfway through when I realized it was The Terminator retold from the point of view of Kyle Reese.

Answer (score 3):

Going to repost this suggestion made by @Krazer from [last time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10269/8350).

### Movie Suggestion: *The Tale of Princess Kaguya*

[image: Not a Miyazaki film]]

*The Tale of The Princess Kaguya* is adapted from the 10th century Japanese folktale "[The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter)," by Studio Ghibli co-founder [Isao Takahata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isao_Takahata) (you may know him from *[Grave of the Fireflies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vPeTSRd580)*, *[Pom Poko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7cowIHjCD4)*). It is the oldest Japanese narrative in existence and an early example of proto-science fiction. The story details the life of a mysterious girl called "Kaguya-hime," who was discovered as a baby inside the stalk of a glowing bamboo plant and is raised by a poor bamboo cutter and his wife.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM6hcHp0_kU) | [Site](http://www.gkidsfilms.com/kaguya/) | [Fresh! (100%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_tale_of_the_princess_kaguya/) | [Content Advisory Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2576852/parentalguide)

*Remarks:* While a Ghibli film, this is *not* a Hayao Miyazaki film. Production of this was done in parallel to *The Wind Rises.* Home release is scheduled for Feb. 17, 2015.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is available on any streaming service.