# Bridge Movie Night 4: A New Movie

Tags: discussion, community-event

Good `<insert time of day>`, everyone. Movie Night's been great fun. Three runs in (technically four with the 2 nights scheduled for *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Big Hero 6*) and I think we have a pretty good understanding on how to handle Movie Night. So, here we go.

- Date: May 23-24 (Saturday, Sunday) at 11:00 PM UTC-0.
- Location: [Bridge Theatre Room](https://rabb.it/yuuki) (spillover rooms will be provided as necessary)

Please post your movie suggestions below. A decision will be reached some time during the start of May. While we welcome any movie suggestion, a movie that is available for streaming (either through Netflix, Google Play, Amazon Prime, etc.) is much preferred.

Comment: A good 10:19PM to you too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Movie Decision: The Lego Movie

[image: Legos, whoo!]

Apologies, apologies for not putting up the decision post until now. Between finals, studying for finals, and procrastinating, I haven't really made time to write this up. In any case, everyone should know that Movie Night will be taking place Saturday and Sunday (5/23-5/24) night. Initial showings will begin at 11:00 PM UTC-0.

Comment: Everything is awsome!

Answer (score 15):

### Movie Suggestion: The Lego Movie

[image: The Lego Movie Poster]

Emmet (Chris Pratt), an ordinary construction worker, thought to be a prophesied 'Special', joins a quest to stop President/Lord Business (Will Ferrell) from releasing the Kragle and freezing the entire universe.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ_JOBCLF-I) | [Official Site](http://www.thelegomovie.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (96%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_lego_movie) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

This is a renomination from [last time](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10361/20306) because I really love this film.

If you look at this and say "this is just going to be a Lego brand cash grab film, isn't it", I can assure you, you are beyond incorrect. It had every opportunity to be a terrible Lego cash grab, but it's so much deeper than that.

Comment: +1 This is a really fun movie. I saw it in theatres and was pleasantly surprised by how much I enjoyed it.

Comment: Everything is awesome!

Comment: @Studoku Especially this movie. :p

Answer (score 8):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Snowpiercer]

In a post-apocalyptic ice age, created by a climate engineering attempt gone wrong, all of humanity lives on the *Snowpiercer*, a massive train that runs around the world. A rigid class system exists on the *Snowpiercer*, where the wealthy elites live at the front of the train while the poor masses live in squalor at the tail. No longer able to stand the terrible conditions in which they live, tail inhabitant Curtis Everett leads a revolution to fight their way to the front of the train and change their way of life.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX5PwfEMBM0) | [Official Site](http://snowpiercer-film.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (95%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/snowpiercer/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/parentalguide)

Comment: This one is long and the storyline is brutally dark.  Might not be good for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

## Movie Suggestion: The BoxTrolls

[image: Movie Poster for The BoxTrolls. Text on poster reads "Heroes come in all shapes and sizes... even rectangles"]

> A family event movie from the creators of Coraline and ParaNorman that introduces audiences to a new breed of family – The Boxtrolls, a community of quirky, mischievous creatures who have lovingly raised a human boy named Eggs (voiced by Isaac Hempstead Wright) in the amazing cavernous home they’ve built beneath the streets of Cheesebridge. When the town’s villain, Archibald Snatcher (Academy Award winner Ben Kingsley), comes up with a plot to get rid of the Boxtrolls, Eggs decides to venture above ground, “into the light,” where he meets and teams up with fabulously feisty Winnie (Elle Fanning). Together, they devise a daring plan to save Eggs’ family. 
>  From [Amazon Product Description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NFZ2S7K)

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2dFVnp5K0o) | [Official Site](http://www.theboxtrolls.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (75%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_boxtrolls/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0787474/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Answer (score 4):

### Movie Suggestion: The Iron Giant

[image: The Iron Giant poster]

A boy befriends a giant alien robot. A paranoid government seeks to destroy it.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgjmFBX34zc) | [Rotten Tomatoes (97%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/iron_giant/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129167/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Redline

[image: Redline Poster]

(Animation, Action, Sci-Fi)

Redline is a racing film created by studio Madhouse (Paprika, The Girl Who Leapt Through Time, Summer Wars). Redline is about the biggest and most deadly racing tournament in the universe. Only held once every five years, everyone wants to stake their claim to fame, including JP, a reckless dare-devil driver oblivious to speed limits with his ultra-customized car - all the while, organized crime and militaristic governments want to leverage the race to their own ends. Amongst the other elite rival drivers in the tournament, JP falls for the alluring Sonoshee - but will she prove his undoing, or can a high speed romance survive a mass destruction race?

Available in both english subbed and dubbed.

This movie looks to be absolute bonkers. Incredible Bonkers. If it's chosen it can be watched in full on youtube, and most other streaming sources.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2t26m_Q6ENo) | [Official Site(in Japanese...)](http://www.tfc-anime.net/redline/index.html) | [Rotten Tomatoes (83%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/redline_2011/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Unrated, but PG-13 probably)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1483797/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Comment: This sounds so incredibly ridiculous, in a good way.

Comment: so is this a more awesome speed racer?

Comment: @GodEmperorDune pretty much.

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: The Princess Bride

[image: The Princess Bride Movie Poster]

A young boy is home sick from school and stuck in bed, so his grandfather comes over to read him a story. It's a story with "Fencing, fighting, torture, revenge, giants, monsters, chases, escapes, true love, miracles...". This isn't just a kissing <del>book</del> movie. It's a story about Buttercup and the farm boy she fell in love with. But when he is killed by the dread-pirate Roberts, and she is set to wed the Prince, true love will be tested.

As a cult classic, not to mention a hilarious and wonderful film, this film is exactly "as you wish."

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtj_Ix5IUo8) | [Official Site](http://princessbrideforever.com/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (97%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/princess_bride/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion - The Dark Crystal

[image: Dark Crystal]

Another planet, another time. 1000 years ago the mysterious Dark Crystal was damaged by one of the Urskeks and an age of chaos has began! The evil race of grotesque birdlike lizards the Skeksis, gnomish dragons who rule their fantastic planet with an iron claw. Meanwhile the orphan Jen, raised in solitude by a race of the peace-loving wizards called the Mystics, embarks on a quest to find the missing shard of the Dark Crystal which gives the Skeksis their power and restore the balance of the universe.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW23YcaBHUg) | [Rotten Tomatoes (71%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/dark_crystal/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083791/parentalguide)

Comment: This is one of those moves I've never watched but probably should.

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Inception

[image]

A thief who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hP9D6kZseM) | [Official Site](http://wwws.warnerbros.co.uk/inception/mainsite/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (86%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Answer (score -2):

## Movie Suggestion: Brick

[image: Brick Poster]

"Brick," while taking its cues and its verbal style from the novels of Dashiell Hammett, also honors the rich cinematic tradition of the hard-boiled noir mystery, here wittily and bracingly immersed in fresh territory - a modern-day Southern California neighborhood and high school. There, student Brendan Frye's piercing intelligence spares no one. Brendan is not afraid to back up his words with actions, and knows all the angles; yet he prefers to stay an outsider, and does - until the day that his ex-girlfriend, Emily reaches out to him unexpectedly and then vanishes. Brendan's feelings for her still run deep; so much so, that he becomes consumed with finding his troubled inamorata. To find her, Brendan enlists the aid of his only true peer, The Brain, while keeping the assistant vice principal only occasionally informed of what quickly becomes a dangerous investigation. Brendan's single-minded unearthing of students' secrets thrusts him headlong into the colliding social orbits of rich-girl sophisticate Laura, intimidating Tugger, substance-abusing Dode, seductive Kara, jock Brad and - most ominously - non-student The Pin. It is only by gaining acceptance into The Pin's closely guarded inner circle of crime and punishment that Brendan will be able to uncover hard truths about himself, Emily and the suspects that he is getting closer to.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM7E0XGiyrc) | [Official Site](http://www.focusfeatures.com/brick/) | [Rotten Tomatoes (80%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/brick/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0393109/parentalguide)

Answer (score -2):

## Movie Suggestion: A Girl Walks Home Alone At Night

Now on Netflix!

[image: A Girl Walks Home Poster]

> The first Iranian Vampire Western ever made, Ana Lily Amirpour’s debut basks in the sheer pleasure of pulp. A joyful mash-up of genre, archetype, and iconography, its prolific influences span spaghetti westerns, graphic novels, horror films, and the Iranian New Wave.

---

> In the Iranian ghost-town Bad City, a place that reeks of death and loneliness, the townspeople are unaware they are being stalked by a lonesome vampire.

---

> Residents of a worn-down Iranian city encounter a skateboarding vampire (Sheila Vand) who preys on men who disrespect women.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YGmTdo3vuY) | [Official Site](http://www.agirlwalkshome.com) | [Rotten Tomatoes (95%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/a_girl_walks_home_alone_at_night/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Unrated)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2326554/parentalguide)