# Bridge Movie Night - February 2017

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

Well, 2016 is finally over. It's been a long year and our first regularly scheduled Bridge Movie Night season. [Can you believe that it's been two years](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/bridge-movie-night)? Putting aside how old I'm making you all feeling, it's time to begin another year of Bridge Movie Nights! Popcorn, the silver screen, exciting stories, and our wonderful Arqade community! Let's have another great year of movie-watching.

A new addition I'm making to our Movie Nights is the introduction of a Google Calendar. I'll post it both here and in the canonical [So You Want to Attend Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night) post when it's ready.

[Scheduling votes will be taken here](http://www.strawpoll.me/12069621) and votes will be tallied and a decision will be made by the end of this month (January).

Comment: I'm thinking I should find out when my work travel is before voting in the straw poll...

Comment: Just curious, as the last one was semi-themed due to being Christmas holidays, but are these usually somewhat themed?

Comment: @Vemonus Not really. In fact, even for the December Movie Night, we don't really have to have a particular theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Movie Night Decision:

[image]

#### Kubo and the Two Strings

The scheduling poll has resulted as follows:

[image]

Now, there's been some talk about what hour to start the showing. For the past several movie nights, the movie has been started at 11:00 PM UTC-0. However, this was due to the first few movie nights beginning on a Friday rather than a Saturday and out of a need to accommodate people who work on weekdays, I had scheduled it then. Now that movie nights are firmly scheduled on Saturdays, I feel that it is appropriate to adjust the showtime to more easily accommodate some of our friends outside of the American continents.

---[Here is a poll with a selection of available times. Pick as many as you can show up to and I'll do my best to pick a schedule that best fits everyone's times](http://doodle.com/poll/rv95t7te5c7fwrpe)--- Movie Night will be occurring at 7:00PM UTC-0.

Answer (score 8):

## Kubo and the Two Strings

This looks like a fun little movie good for the whole family, with some pretty solid animation. The critical reception to the movie was been really positive as well. Summary courtesy of google is:

> Young Kubo's  peaceful existence comes crashing down when he accidentally summons a vengeful spirit from the past. Now on the run, Kubo joins forces with Monkey and Beetle  to unlock a secret legacy. Armed with a magical instrument, Kubo must battle the Moon King  and other gods and monsters to save his family and solve the mystery of his fallen father, the greatest samurai warrior the world has ever known.

[image]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4302938/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 97%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/kubo_and_the_two_strings_2016/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfApAsZKKcg)

Answer (score 5):

## Hell or High Water

This is different from the movies we normally watch, but it looks good, and the critical reception was been positive. Essentially, in order to protect his family ranch and provide for his son a man teams up with his brother (who's an ex-con) to rob a bank. Summary courtesy of IMBD:

> A divorced father and his ex-con older brother resort to a desperate scheme in order to save their family's ranch in West Texas.

[image]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582782/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 98%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/hell_or_high_water/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQoqsKoJVDw)

Answer (score 4):

## Viva Amiga

I'm not sure if documentaries are up for consideration, but this one covers the rise and fall of the Commodore Amiga and the culture that developed around it, which I think would be interesting to people here.

From IMDB:

> In a world of green on black, they dared to dream in color. 1985: An upstart team of Silicon Valley mavericks created a miracle: the Amiga computer. A machine made for creativity. For games, for art, for expression. Breaking from the mold set by IBM and Apple, this was something new. Something to change what people believed computers could do. 2016: The future they saw isn't the one we live in now. Or is it? From the creation of the world's first multimedia digital art powerhouse, to a bankrupt shell sold and resold into obscurity, to a post-punk spark revitalized by determined fans. Viva Amiga is a look at a digital dream and the freaks, geeks and geniuses who brought it to life. And the Amiga is still alive.

[image]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6398570/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHCxvZJW1S8)

Answer (score 3):

## District 9

I see GnomeSlice's relevance, and raise more relevant. Idea shamelessly stolen. Sue me. In addition to being relevant, this is also a good movie.

> An extraterrestrial race forced to live in slum-like conditions on Earth suddenly finds a kindred spirit in a government agent who is exposed to their biotechnology.

[image: District 9 movie poster]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 90%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/district_9) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyLUwOcR5pk) | [Content Advisory (rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: Last minute entry, will re-enter next time around if it doesn't suddenly defeat Kubo

Comment: I'll even re-enter Kubo if this does beat it

Comment: This is one of my all-time favourite movies.  And I *still* find a lot of it hard to watch.

Answer (score 2):

Old spy movie based in WW2 starring Richard Burton and Clint Eastwood. I watched it back in the day and thought it was pretty interesting and had some pretty good acting.

> Allied agents stage a daring raid on a castle where the Nazis are holding an American General prisoner... but that's not all that's really going on.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065207/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 88%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/where_eagles_dare/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OpMRRgTseI)

Answer (score 2):

## Idiocracy

Relevant.

> Private Joe Bauers, the definition of "average American", is selected by the Pentagon to be the guinea pig for a top-secret hibernation program. Forgotten, he awakes five centuries in the future. He discovers a society so incredibly dumbed down that he's easily the most intelligent person alive.

[image]

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 74%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/idiocracy/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBvIweCIgwk)