# Bridge Movie Night - June 2017

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

[Oh my, it's been awhile!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/bridge-movie-night-february-2017) Unfortunately, we had some technical difficulties at our last movie night, which put showings on an indefinite hiatus. Luckily, I've found a solution that should require no extra effort on your part so we can continue with Movie Night. Now as this is somewhat late notice, the decision period will be rather short, a week to be precise. So get your proposals in and vote on them by June 2, I'll make the decision then.

[Vote on the scheduling here](http://www.strawpoll.me/13068621), that decision will be finalized on June 2 as well.

---

The votes are in, and a date has been set! Please see [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12482/145980) for details.

Comment: Is there a theme? Also, you might want to check out our [history of film nights](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7431/70236) (and the posts linked to it), ust in case.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, we don't generally have a theme. Just a random assortment of whatever someone wants to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image]

### Moana

Date: **June 10, 2017 at 7:00 PM UTC-0.**

The [movie room](https://rabb.it/yuuki) should be open roughly 5-10 minutes before the scheduled time. At 7:00 PM, I'll do a quick attendance and the movie will begin shortly.

Comment: Would you mind editing this info into the question post (or linking to this answer)? I didn't realize until just now a date was set, even though I checked the thread daily.

Comment: Actually I guess I could do that myself, never mind :P

Answer (score 8):

## Moana

> In Ancient Polynesia, when a terrible curse incurred by the Demigod Maui reaches an impetuous Chieftain's daughter's island, she answers the Ocean's call to seek out the Demigod to set things right.

[image: ![Moana movie poster]

[IMDB 7.7](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3521164/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 96%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/moana_2016/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKFuXETZUsI) | [Content Advisory (rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3521164/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: I love this movie. I will happily watch it again and again and again.

Comment: If this gets picked, I expect a comment under the announcement along the lines of "What can I say except you're welcome"

Comment: We should try and consider the coconut before picking this movie.

Comment: Oh crap, haven't seen this yet and I really want to.  Now I need to know how to participate in movie night.

Comment: @BlueBarren https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night

Answer (score 4):

### Suggestion: [*Watchmen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen_(film))

[image]
 <sub>[Poster source](http://www.watchmencomicmovie.com/watchmen-movie-posters.php)</sub>

The film an adaptation of the [eponymous graphic novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen) by Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons.

[image]
 <sub>Source: [DC Comics](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/watchmen)</sub>

The film is set in the third term of Richard Nixon's presidency, and the Cold War is still on. Watchmen are a group of costumed vigilantes who, each with different motivations, fight crime, usually on street level.

> In an alternate 1985 America, costumed superheroes are part of everyday life. When one of his former comrades is murdered, masked vigilante Rorschach uncovers a plot to kill and discredit all past and present superheroes. As he reconnects with his retired associates, only one of which has true powers, Rorschach glimpses a far-reaching conspiracy involving their shared past and catastrophic consequences for the world's future.
>   <sub>From the Google blurb</sub>

The graphic novel, as well as the film, is notable for its depiction of anti-heroes, as opposed to superheroes.

[image: Dr. Manhattan] [image: Comedian] [image: Nite Owl 2]
[image: Ozymandias] [image: Silk Spectre II] [image: Rorschach]
 <sub>[Poster source](http://www.watchmencomicmovie.com/watchmen-movie-posters.php)</sub>

[IMDB 7.6](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 65%](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/watchmen/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVjA0y78_EQ) | [Other trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUjMO_k9IF8) | Content Advisory: [Google Play said 7+](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Watchmen?id=hjmRo-XJuUM), but [IMDB says R](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/parentalguide), for lots of gore, violence, and some sex scenes. I imagine the theatrical cut is less adult than the extended cut, but still.